# Program to find maximum in each row of csv file and put those values in a empty excel file

Tags: python, excel, max

I have csv file of IMD data for rainfall. I would like to use a python program to find the maximum value of each row in the csv file and that maximum value to be saved in a column name - ND of the excel file.

```
import csv

max_list = []
f = open('IMD-RAINFALL1902_rain.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
for row in csv_f:
    maxi = max(row)
    max_list.append(maxi)
    print(maxi)
```

If someone could help me with adding max_list to ND column of the excel file, it would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for a python-script or excel formula? For helping you with the code you have to provide any code. Otherwise you are asking for someone coding _for_ you. Please edit your question and have a look at a [Minimal Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The question has been edited. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

For tabluar data you should use the *pandas* package. It comes with many useful tools for analysing data. In your case you can change all your code to:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(path=??, sep="??")
print(df.head())
```

Just replace the ?? with your file path and seperator (I guess `;`)
`df.head()` gives you the first 5 lines of your data, so you can check whether loading was succesfull. If not, have a look into the [reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) if additional arguments are needed in your case. (Header, Index etc.)